# form data edit with angular 9 and ngrx throwing an error

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I am trying to implement the form edit using angular and ngrx. I am able to access the form data using the ngrx and passing down to child component and it is displaying fine. But when I tried to edit the field I am getting "ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '#fieldname' of object '[object Object]'". Below is the snippet of code I am using.

Parent Component:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.formData$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromData.getData));
 }

<app-child [afeData]="formData$ | async">
</app-child>
```

Child Component

```
  <label>Name</label>
  <input id="input" type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.name">
  <button type="button" (click)="SubmitData($event);" label="Save"></button>
```

When I deep clone the response form data using  JSON.parse like below on parent component then it works fine. Is there better way to achieve this without deep cloning the object?

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
      this.store.pipe(select(fromData.getData)).subscribe(res =>{
          this.fromData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)); 
   });


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a redux store like ngrx is to use your application in a reactive way.

event -> store -> view

You use an action to update the store and a selector with observable get his data.

So you have to split your component access from  [(ngModel)]="formData.name" to something like  [ngModel]="formDataname" (change)="onChange($event)".

Best with NgRx is to use reactive forms.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's time to start using [_lodash](https://lodash.com/),
_.cloneDeep() [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep)

Comment: My app is working fine if I do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)). I guess not a good idea to use _loadash just for this. This is very common thing on form edit and I am expecting better way to achieve this without cloning the object.